# Can someone tell me what is this encryption method?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

DQUC//S+y9uZxanuAS0WTQBlAG4AZQBkAHwBZQByACAAegBhAGQAYQBEASAAVwBpAG4AZABvAHcAcwAC3/n9tdqZxanuASkUTwByAGMAdQBzACAAQQBkAG0AaQBuAGkAcwB0AHIAYQB0AGkAbwBuAALfreWG2JnFqe4BGQxPAHIAYwB1AHMAIABTAGUAcgB2AGUAcgAABgY=

its important for me i need to know this how can i decode it simply

Answer (score 2):

This isn't encrypted, it's just Base64 encoded. Stick it into [this website](https://www.base64decode.org/) and you'll see:

> ũ-Mened|er zadaD Windowsũ)Orcus Administration߭ũOrcus Server